# Writing out a (set) relation in terms of predicate logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification, relations, predicate-logic

Revisiting some elementary binary relations on $\mathbb{R}$ while studying predicate logic (at a graduate level), I wanted to receive some criticism on the following thoughts I have.

---

Lets take a look at this binary relation (that is a function) on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$:
$f :=$ {$(x,y)| y = x^{2}$}. Since we know that a relation is just a predicate of two variables (or "subjects", if you will) that produces a truth value, couldn't we write the  relation $f$ as the following  assuming I was a student who had never taken set theory (but knew that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers in the proposition $f(x,y)$)? That is, knowing that “is the square of” is the predicate $f$ where $x$ and $y$ are the subjects:

$f(x,y) :=$ $y$ is the square of $x$

Since a course in the logic of propositions and predicates is usually taken before set theory at my university, I feel like this would occur naturally as an example. Of course, reoccurring later in a set theory course as $f :=$ {$(x,y)| y = x^{2}$} where the proposition $f(x,y)$ is rewritten (set-theoretically) as $y = f(x):= x^{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some subtleties that can be unpacked here.

In the context of first-order logic; "$y$ is the square of $x$" is an informal describtion of the relation you want to have. This is fine, as long as you can justfy it with a formal describtion.
In your question, we find ourselfs in the context of the real numbers. A first-order language for $\mathbb{R}$ would surely provide us with the symbols "$\cdot$" and "$=$", so we could properly state the relation as:
$$
f(x,y) := (x \cdot x = y)
$$
which is then a relation **in the first-order language of $\mathbb{R}$**.

In set theory we can realize the relation as a set by using the [axiom of specifictiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification)
$$
F := \{(x,y) \mid x \cdot x =y~\}
$$
Now one can be nitpicky here as well. The linked article mentions that the specifying formula on the right (in this case $x \cdot x =y$) has to be a formula **in the language of set theory**. So the above is only jsutified if "$\cdot$" was at some point defined by a formula in the language of set-theory.

But to answer your question:

> Couldn't we write the relation $f$ as the following [...] ?

Yes that is completely fine. Everything mentioned above are only very technical nitpicks that rarely come up and do not pose unsurmountable problems.

---

There is one bit of notation you used, that you do have to be carefull about.

> [...] where the proposition $f(x,y)$ is rewritten (set-theoretically) as $y=f(x):=x^2$.

Not every binary relation is a function. The notation $f(x) = y$ is only used when $f$ is a [functional relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Special_types_of_binary_relations). With your definition, $f$ indeed turns out to be functional. However, if we were to define
$$
g(x, y) := x \text{ is the square of } y 
$$
Then $g$ would not be functional, since for example $g(4,2) ~\land~ g (4 ,-2)$ but $2 \neq -2$. So we can not write something like $g(4) = 2$.

Comment: Thank you for your time in this explanation! Everything you stated is crystal clear.